# Ruby's equivalent of Groovy's metaclass.method_name

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass

I have a method where `symbol_price` is a hash with keys as symbols and price as values.

```
def get_price_for_symbol(symbol_price, symbol)
  symbol_price[symbol]
end
```

In Groovy if we want to mock out the main class method `get_price_for_symbol` we write in test class:

```
object.metaClass.get_price_for_symbol = { symbol_price, symbol -> 99.987 }
```

How we do similar thing in Ruby?

Comment: Yes. symbol price is a hash in test class

Comment: My apologies (written with a very red face).  Somehow I failed to notice that the hash was an argument! I suggest you delete your comment, then I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

The most equivalente thing in Ruby is to redefine the method in your test but you should consider use dependency injection to avoid doing this kind of things. Anyway, here we go:

```
instance = Object.new

def instance.get_price_for_symbol(_, _) 
  99.987
end
```